# Lock Range (in the same row) when A"counter" is TRUE

Tags: excel, vba

[Click Here To see and understand my TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2j4q.png)

IF A2 is TRUE I want to lock the Range D2:I2

IF A3 is TRUE I want to lock the Range D3:I3...

IF AxRow is TRUE I want to lock the Range DxRow:IxRow

I have 744 rows (A2:A745) with TRUE or FALSE statements that are results of the following equation A2=IF($C$2>B2,TRUE,FALSE). 
**C2** is showing to me "30.1545" which means the time now, Day 30 November, 15h45 that is updated automatically (i.e., after 20 minutes is going to be "30.1605"). The cells **B2 till B745** shows the month's days and a linked hour with a fixed value (B2 = 01.0700 [1 November 7AM], B3 = 01.0800 [1 November 8AM],...,B706 = 30.1500 [30 November 15PM],B707 = 30.1600 [30 November 16PM],...).

When the FALSE statement appears, all the following cells are FALSE, as you can see $C$2 = 30.1545 < B707 = 30.1600, so A707 = FALSE and so on.

Actual example: A2 =TRUE ...A704 = TRUE, A705 = TRUE, A706 = TRUE, A707 = FALSE, A708 = FALSE... A745 = FALSE.

Please, **what is the problem with my code**? It doesn't shows any error message, it just feels like that Excel locked and unlocked the cells that were supposed to be locked.

```
Private Sub Block(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

Dim xRow As Long
xRow = 2
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="123"
Do Until Cells(xRow, 1).Value = False
If Worksheets("HourlyCount").Cells(xRow, 1).Value = True Then
Range("D" & xRow & ":I" & xRow).Locked = True
End If
xRow = xRow + 1
Loop
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="123"


End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you tell us what the problem is and then we can try to help fix it. What happens when you run the code? Does it produce an error? Does nothing happen? Does something unexpected happen? Does your computer spontaneously explode? idk

Comment: Also, are these `TRUE`/`FALSE` typed into the cells or are they a result of an equation?

Comment: Is `HourlyCount` the `ActiveSheet`?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I updated my question with more details! Reply: TRUE/FALSE are result of an equation and HourlyCount is the ActiveSheet, no Error message.

Answer (score 0):

If your `TRUE`/`FALSE` cells are actually text values and not the result of an equation you will need to wrap `FALSE` in quotes in the below code (`If ws.Range("A" & i) = "FALSE" Then`)

Also....

- You need to qualify your objects (ranges, cells, etc) with a valid worksheet. Otherwise, you may be referring to the wrong sheet. My code assumes all objects in question exist on the same sheet (`Sheet1`)
- It is easier to use `Range(Cells(), Cells())` to build a multi variable range which replaces your `.Locked = True` statement.

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub Blockade()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim LR As Long, i As Long

LR = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

ws.Unprotect "123"
    For i = 2 To LR
        If ws.Range("A" & i) = False Then
            ws.Range(ws.Cells(i, 4), ws.Cells(i, 9)).Locked = True
        End If
    Next i
ws.Protect "123"

End Sub
```

---

You could also reduce your loop to below code. The statement `Range = False` will yeild either `TRUE` or `FALSE` which will determine if a range is locked or not

```
ws.Unprotect "123"
    For i = 2 To LR
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(i, 4), ws.Cells(i, 9)).Locked = ws.Range("A" & i) = False
    Next i
ws.Protect "123"
```

Comment: Or `ws.Range(ws.Cells(i, 4), ws.Cells(i, 9)).Locked = Not ws.Range("A" & i)` (providing you can guarantee that column A contains TRUE/FALSE).

Comment: Ohhhh I like that. Thanks @DarrenBartrup-Cook , will likely start using that in the future